# Icons renew after node moveup/movedown

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I have a virtualstringtree with icons in an imagelist. Everything works great but when i select a node and move it up or down, the Caption of the node changes but the icon doesn't change.

When i built the tree, i asertain the icons and then i put it in an imagelist

```
    imgIcon:= TIcon.Create;
    imgIcon.LoadFromFile(Path);
    imgFTree.AddIcon(imgIcon);
    imgIcon.Free;
```

In the GetImageIndex event the code is:

```
    ImageIndex:= Sender.AbsoluteIndex(Node);
```

Does anyone knows what's wrong?

Comment: The `AbsoluteIndex` is an index of the node hierarchy. It's not unique for the node.

Comment: TLama: Do you have any idea i can solve my problem?

Comment: Yep, store the image index into the user data of each node.

Comment: Thx - this was the right tip!